# Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS: Can't manage to run my wireless connection

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, wireless, server

I've just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS and during the installation, I've set up SSID and WPA key and the installer seemed to accept it. However after booting the system there is no connection.

`ifconfig -a` doesn't show wlan0

`/etc/network/interfaces` has proper settings

`lspci -nn` shows the wireless controller

```
Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
```

yet `ifconfig wlan0 up` returns no such device

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

try reading:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration
this will help you list information or configure your device.
here is a thread where wlan0 does not show in ifconfig
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116182